# Is there a .NET Framework method for converting file URIs to paths with drive letters?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uri

I was looking for something like Server.MapPath in the ASP.NET realm to convert the output of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase into a file path with drive letter.

The following code works for the test cases I've tried:

```
private static string ConvertUriToPath(string fileName)
{
    fileName = fileName.Replace("file:///", "");
    fileName = fileName.Replace("/", "\\");
    return fileName;
}
```

It seems like there should be something in the .NET Framework that would be much better--I just haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Scott's answer is what you want, but I'm out of votes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert Assembly.CodeBase into a filesystem path in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107625/how-can-i-convert-assembly-codebase-into-a-filesystem-path-in-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try looking at the [Uri.LocalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx) property.

```
private static string ConvertUriToPath(string fileName)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri(fileName);
   return uri.LocalPath;

   // Some people have indicated that uri.LocalPath doesn't 
   // always return the corret path. If that's the case, use
   // the following line:
   // return uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked for an answer a lot, and the most popular answer is using [Uri.LocalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx). But System.Uri fails to give correct LocalPath if the Path contains “#”. Details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896572/system-uri-fails-to-give-correct-absolutepath-and-localpath-if-the-path-contains).

My solution is:

```
private static string ConvertUriToPath(string fileName)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri(fileName);
   return uri.LocalPath + Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Fragment).Replace('/', '\\');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `Assembly.Location`?

Comment: I can't use Assembly.Location because it's non-static and the method where I'd need to make the call from is static.

Comment: Assembly.Location may not be what you're looking for, but it's not because it's a non-static method.  Remember that you can instantiate new object within a static member.

Comment: Assembly.Current.Location or Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Answer (score 0):

Location can be different to CodeBase.
E.g. for files in ASP.NET it likely to be resolved under  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET. 
See "Assembly.CodeBase vs. Assembly.Location"
http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/06/26/57198.aspx