# System.Uri fails to give correct AbsolutePath and LocalPath if the Path contains "#"

Tags: c#, .net

I have C# code that is trying to get the `LocalPath` for a executing assembly using the following line of code:

`Uri uri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;`

This piece of code performs fine for all the variety of paths.  It started to fail giving the right `AbsolutePath` and `Localpath` because the executing assembly path contained a # in it.

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` gives `"C:\c#\ExcelAddin1.1.0\GSRExcelPlugin\bin\Debug\Common.dll"`

But new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath gives "C:\c" while it should have given "C:\c#\ExcelAddin1.1.0\GSRExcelPlugin\bin\Debug\".

Is there something that I need to handle or is there something wrong the way Uri class is used?

If this is a .net framework issue, how should I report this issue to Microsoft?

Answer (score 7):

```
System.IO.FileInfo logger = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath), "settings.config"));
```

Using EscapedCodeBase instead of CodeBase solves the problem. I dint realize that this was already handled until I stumbled on it.:)

Comment: Damn: Does NOT work with a directory like: `Test\Space( )(#)(%20){[&],@,%}\Release` ... the %20 is not handled correctly

Comment: This solution worked for me, and I have a space, a (x86) character and a # in the path. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `Uri` class is behaving as expected. `#` is not a valid part of a url. Imo this is an issue with `CodeBase` property. It returns a string unescaping special characters rendering it pretty much unreliable. Your options are:

1) Always use `EscapedCodeBase` property instead.

```
var uri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath;
```

2) Or if you really have to deal with `CodeBase` property (if that is the only option), get the escaped part yourself.

```
var x = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
var uri = x.LocalPath + Uri.UnescapeDataString(x.Fragment).Replace('/', '\\');
```

3) For file location of the loaded assembly, the easiest is to use `Location` property.

```
var uri = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

The issue has been reported several times, but MS insists that is how `CodeBase` is designed [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748220/codebase-does-not-correctly-escape-character), [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750678/codebase-does-not-correctly-escape-character), [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/333763/assembly-codebase-returns-invalid-uris-for-paths-containing-hashes) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798785/system-reflection-assembly-codebase-property-and-getting-local-path-from-it-available-apis-are-insufficient).

Comment: At least `Uri` is consistent with itself. If I do `new Uri(new Uri("C:\\"), "#%23")`, I get `file:///C:/%23%2523` out (meaning it treats the interpolated path as a file path instead of a URI-style path).

Answer (score 1):

I assume The URI functions are stripping away everything after the sharp `#` because it thinks its an anchor.

URI are designed for identifying resources on the internet, so your  `#` character would be an illegal character in the middle of any URI.

Take even this question for example, the Title is

*System.Uri fails to give correct AbsolutePath and LocalPath if the Path contains “#”*

but the end of the URL has the "#" stripped away

[system-uri-fails-to-give-correct-absolutepath-and-localpath-if-the-path-contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896572/system-uri-fails-to-give-correct-absolutepath-and-localpath-if-the-path-contains)

Why do you need to convert it into a URI anyway. The only difference between these 3 console.writelines is the fact that the first two are prefixed with `File:///`

```
Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);  // 1
Uri uri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
Console.WriteLine(uri);                                       // 2
Console.WriteLine(uri.LocalPath);                             // 3
```