# How Can I Remove The 'file:\\' From the Return Value of Path.GetDirectoryName() in C#

Tags: c#, path

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(
                     Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).CodeBase);
```

output:

**file:\d:\learning\cs\test\test.xml**

What's the best way to return only **d:\learning\cs\test\test.xml**

`file:\\` will throw exception when I call `doc.Save(returnPath)` ,however `doc.Load(returnPath)`; works well.  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a .NET Framework method for converting file URIs to paths with drive letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278761/is-there-a-net-framework-method-for-converting-file-uris-to-paths-with-drive-le)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the directory of the assembly of that class, you could use the [`Assembly.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) property:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).Location);
```

This isn't exactly the same as the `CodeBase` property, though.  The `Location` is the "path or UNC location of the loaded file that contains the manifest" whereas the `CodeBase` is the " location of the assembly as specified originally, for example, in an AssemblyName object".

Comment: Thanks for your Simple but perfect solution.   @all, Thank you.

Comment: Location is the assembly location after shadow copying, while CodeBase is the original location, before the shadow copying happened. So if shadow copying is enabled, and you want the original location, one must use CodeBase.

Answer (score 61):

```
string path = new Uri(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).CodeBase).LocalPath;
```

Comment: I'd like to add that, while Chris' solution was marked as Answer, it was Matthew's solution that actually provided a proper solution to the question in the title and to my problem: How to convert a file:// style path to a C:\ style path. Thanks Matthew !

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if you have any invalid URI character (for example, the sharp one #) this will be omitted by new Uri() function and your path will be wrong. You will have to use something like WebUtility.UrlEncode in order to correctly get the right path.

Comment: @Fabiano I have a path with #, using UrlEncode throws an exception when running new Uri(WebUtility.UrlEncode(myWeirdPath)); Alternatives?

Answer (score 9):

```
  System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).CodeBase);
  string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.LocalPath);
```

Comment: I noticed that the spaces in the path were replaced with "%20" if I used System.Uri

Comment: @AlexKoshulyan - you are right for some properties of Uri, like AbsolutePath. But Uri.LocalPath does not seem to replace spaces with %20  - at least from what I can see.

Answer (score 4):

My first approach would be like this...

```
path = path.Replace("file://", "");
```

Comment: While this might answer the question in hand for OP, this is a poor solution. The uri class handles a lot more corner cases.

Comment: @nawfal - "The uri class handles a lot more corner cases"...and it also introduces plenty of corner cases of its own.  For example, if the CodeBase for your assembly is in file:///c:/temp/#my_test#/WindowsFormsApplication1/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApplication1.EXE and you pass that CodeBase value to the Uri constructor, you get c:\\temp for uri.LocalPath. The hash characters cause it not to work as one would hope it would.

Comment: Another problem is when running on linux. There the result would be "file:/home/something" where you only need to remove "file:"

Answer (score 0):

use the substring string method to grab the file name after file:\