# How can I convert Assembly.CodeBase into a filesystem path in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, codebase

I have a project that stores templates in a `\Templates` folder next to the DLLs and EXE.

I want to determine this file path at runtime, but using a technique that will work inside a unit test as well as in production (and I don't want to disable shadow-copying in NUnit!)

`Assembly.Location` is no good because it returns the shadow-copied assembly's path when running under NUnit.

`Environment.CommandLine` is also of limited use because in NUnit et al it returns the path to NUnit, not to my project.

`Assembly.CodeBase` looks promising, but it's a UNC path:

```
file:///D:/projects/MyApp/MyApp/bin/debug/MyApp.exe
```

Now I *could* turn this into a local filesystem path using string manipulation, but I suspect there's a cleaner way of doing it buried in the .NET framework somewhere. Anyone know a recommended way of doing this?

(Throwing an exception if the UNC path is not a `file:///` URL is absolutely fine in this context)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a .NET Framework method for converting file URIs to paths with drive letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278761/is-there-a-net-framework-method-for-converting-file-uris-to-paths-with-drive-le)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You need to use System.Uri.LocalPath:

```
string localPath = new Uri("file:///D:/projects/MyApp/MyApp/bin/debug/MyApp.exe").LocalPath;
```

So if you want the original location of the currently executing assembly:

```
string localPath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
```

The LocalPath includes the assembly's file name, e.g.,

```
D:\projects\MyApp\MyApp\bin\debug\MyApp.exe
```

If you want the assembly's directory, then use System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName():

```
string localDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);
```

which will give you:

```
D:\projects\MyApp\MyApp\bin\debug
```

Comment: Note that this does not work when a directory has a '#' in its name

Comment: Key here is to use `Uri.LocalPath` - we had a bug were we used `Uri.AbsolutePath`, which seems to work until you have a space in the path name!

Comment: And actually, if you have a path that contains `%20`for example, even `LocalPath` wont work. (Which might be acceptable .... local paths containing any `%xx`escape are rather rare. See this comment on other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in/283917#comment3340848_283917

Comment: **Note:** Even with `EscapedCodeBase`, this answer _can be incorrect_ for some use cases. See @MartinBa's answer below for why and use his solution if you value correctness over ease of development.

Comment: A real gem. For some reason Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase started returning a different result, or Path.GetDirectoryName() lost the ability to parse that result. Very strange, but atleast there is this solution.

Comment: It is safer to use `new Uri(assembly.EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath`, but even this can fail because `EscapedCodeBase` improperly escapes the path `Space( )(h#)(p%20){[a&],t@,p%,+}` as `Space(%20)(h%23)(p%20)%7B%5Ba%26%5D,t@,p%,+%7D.,` which unescapes to `Space( )(h#)(p ){[a&],t@,p%,+}.,` (the `%20` in the path was changed to a space.)

Answer (score 30):

> Assembly.CodeBase looks promising, but it's a UNC path:

Do note that it is something approximating a [file uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), *not* an [UNC path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx).

---

You solve this by doing string manipulation by hand. *Seriously.*

Try all other methods you can find on SO with the following directory (verbatim):

```
C:\Test\Space( )(h#)(p%20){[a&],t@,p%,+}.,\Release
```

This is a valid, if somewhat unusual, Windows path. (Some people *will* have either one of these characters in there paths, and you would want you method to work for *all* of those, right?)

The available code base ([we do not want `Location`, right?](https://web.archive.org/web/20101010144616/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/26/assembly-codebase-vs-assembly-location.aspx)) properties are then (on my Win7 with .NET 4):

```
assembly.CodeBase -> file:///C:/Test/Space( )(h#)(p%20){[a&],t@,p%,+}.,/Release

assembly.EscapedCodeBase -> file:///C:/Test/Space(%20)(h%23)(p%20)%7B%5Ba%26%5D,t@,p%,+%7D.,/Release
```

You will note:

- `CodeBase` is not escaped at all, it's just the regular local path prefixed with `file:///` and the backslashes replaced. As such, it *does not* work to feed this to `System.Uri`.
- `EscapedCodeBase` is not escaped completely (I do *not* know if this is a bug or if this is a shortcoming of the [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)):

  - Note how the space character ( ) translates to `%20`
  - but the `%20` sequence *also* translates to `%20`! (percent `%` is not escaped at all)
  - *No one* can rebuild the original from this mangled form!

For local files (And that's really all I'd care about for the `CodeBase`stuff, because if the file ain't local, you probably want to use `.Location` anyway, the following works for me (note that it isn't the prettiest either:

```
    public static string GetAssemblyFullPath(Assembly assembly)
    {
        string codeBasePseudoUrl = assembly.CodeBase; // "pseudo" because it is not properly escaped
        if (codeBasePseudoUrl != null) {
            const string filePrefix3 = @"file:///";
            if (codeBasePseudoUrl.StartsWith(filePrefix3)) {
                string sPath = codeBasePseudoUrl.Substring(filePrefix3.Length);
                string bsPath = sPath.Replace('/', '\\');
                Console.WriteLine("bsPath: " + bsPath);
                string fp = Path.GetFullPath(bsPath);
                Console.WriteLine("fp: " + fp);
                return fp;
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, "CodeBase evaluation failed! - Using Location as fallback.");
        return Path.GetFullPath(assembly.Location);
    }
```

I am sure one can come up with better solutions, probably one could even come up with a solution that does proper URL en-/decoding of the `CodeBase` property if it's a local path, but given that one can just strip off the `file:///` and be done with it, I'd say this solution stands as good enough, if *certainly* really ugly.

Comment: If it's a UNC path it's file://server/share/path/to/assembly.dll (only 2 slashes).

Comment: @Joshua - you mean to say that a `\\server\...` path is encoded with only two slashes, instead of the 3 when having a local drive?

Comment: @Joshua - do you know how `\\?\UNC\server\share` paths are encoded?

Comment: My testing failed to get a \\?\UNC form to be accepted at all; maybe it's not valid for the underlying API call.

Comment: That is fantastic, but any reason in particular you would replace / to \ ? Wouldn't that only cause issues with mono on other platforms?

Comment: @BjarkeCK no specific reason for '/' vs '\'. My code was for Windows only. Shouldn't a sane Mono Path.GetFullPath implementation handle BS correctly?

Comment: @BjarkeCK you could use Path.DirectorySeparatorChar to mitigate that issue.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
String path = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(asm.EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath);

string strLog4NetConfigPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "log4net.config");
```

I am using this to be able to log from within the dll libraries using a standalone log4net.config file.

Answer (score 4):

One more solution, including complex paths:

```
    public static string GetPath(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.GetFileName());
    }

    public static string GetFileName(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        return assembly.CodeBase.GetPathFromUri();
    }

    public static string GetPathFromUri(this string uriString)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(uriString));
        return String.Format("{0}{1}", Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.PathAndQuery), Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Fragment));
    }
```

and tests:

```
    [Test]
    public void GetPathFromUriTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(@"C:/Test/Space( )(h#)(p%20){[a&],t@,p%,+}.,/Release", @"file:///C:/Test/Space( )(h#)(p%20){[a&],t@,p%,+}.,/Release".GetPathFromUri());
        Assert.AreEqual(@"C:/Test/Space( )(h#)(p%20){[a&],t@,p%,+}.,/Release",  @"file://C:/Test/Space( )(h#)(p%20){[a&],t@,p%,+}.,/Release".GetPathFromUri());
    }

    [Test]
    public void AssemblyPathTest()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        var path = asm.GetPath();
        var file = asm.GetFileName();

        Assert.IsNotEmpty(path);
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(file);

        Assert.That(File     .Exists(file));
        Assert.That(Directory.Exists(path));
    }
```

Comment: Nice! But I'd prefer backslashes, so I'd pass the result from `GetPathFromUri` through `Path.GetFullPath`.

Comment: You'll need to take the Uri.Host into account in order to support network paths.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this question **NUnit**, you can also use `AssemblyHelper.GetDirectoryName` to get the original directory of the executing assembly:

```
using System.Reflection;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
...
string path = AssemblyHelper.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
```